# Usercontrol autosize border

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm creating a group of `Controls` in an `UserControl`. But the border of the second `UserControl` also draws around the first drawn `UserControl`. 
Here a video to illustrate what I mean: https://vid.me/e/rZ3N How can I make the border only to be drawn around the `UserControl` itself?

This is the `UserControl` class I add the `Controls` to

```
public class GroupUserControl : UserControl
{
    private Point mDown { get; set; }
    private Point conLoc { get; set; }

    public GroupUserControl()
    {
        AutoSize = true;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        mDown = e.Location;
        conLoc = this.Location;
    }


    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call MyBase.OnMouseMove to activate the delegate. 
        base.OnMouseMove(e);


        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Location = new Point(e.X + Left - mDown.X, e.Y + Top - mDown.Y);
        }
    }


}
```

`TreeView` drag drop method

```
    private void shapeTreeView_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode", true))
        {
            // node exists in drag data payload
            Point pt = this.shapeTreeView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));


            // Get a handle to the destination node. This will become the parent of our new node.
            TreeNode DestinationNode = this.shapeTreeView.GetNodeAt(pt);

            // Create the new node based on the dragged node
            TreeNode newNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode");

            // Check destination mode
            if (!(DestinationNode == newNode) && DestinationNode.Text=="Group")
            {
                TreeNode newNodeClone = (TreeNode)newNode.Clone();//add

                // add a clone
                //DestinationNode.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)newNode.Clone());
                DestinationNode.Nodes.Add(newNodeClone);

                // expand the new node
                DestinationNode.Expand();

                // remove the original node
                newNode.Remove();

                //add - create groups of controls drag under construction
                if (newNodeClone.PrevNode != null)
                {
                    Control prevControl = (Control)newNodeClone.PrevNode.Tag;
                    Control control = (Control)newNodeClone.Tag;

                    var compositeGraphic = (CompositeGraphic)DestinationNode.Tag;


                    if (!compositeGraphic.uc.Contains(prevControl))
                    {
                        compositeGraphic.uc.Controls.Add(prevControl);
                    }
                    if (!compositeGraphic.uc.Controls.Contains(control))
                    {
                        compositeGraphic.uc.Controls.Add(control);
                    }

                    if (!panel.Controls.Contains(compositeGraphic.uc))
                    {
                        panel.Controls.Add(compositeGraphic.uc);
                    }
                }

                var parent = newNodeClone.Parent;

                if (parent == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    var compositeGraphic = (CompositeGraphic)DestinationNode.Tag/*newNodeClone.Parent.Tag*/; //Kan ook veranderd naar destination node  >?
                    string shapeType = newNodeClone.Text;

                    switch (shapeType)
                    {
                        case "Ellipse":
                            Ellipse el = (Ellipse)newNodeClone.Tag;
                            compositeGraphic.Add(el);
                            break;
                        case "Box":
                            Box b = (Box)newNodeClone.Tag;
                            compositeGraphic.Add(b);
                            break;
                    }
                    //compositeGraphic.Print();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried to you set the AutoSizeMode to GrowAndShrink, May be it is not updating it's bound with respect to the content it has.

Comment: @NiranjanKala I already tried that, but the result is the same.

Comment: @NiranjanKala any other ideas?

Comment: If it is not working then specify the size control manually by checking bounds all children..

Comment: @NiranjanKala how to do that?

Comment: It looks like second group contains first group as a child. Can you post related code (where you check what second group has >2 items and do something to display it, probably adding it as child to container, adding 2 circles to it and then adding first group as a child as well)?

Comment: @Sinatr added the `TreeView` drag drop

Comment: Set breakpoint after you doing `Add` and see what is happening with `uc.Controls` after each action. It's hard to follow the logic, but I still think you are adding previous group somehow. Sorry, can't help you any more, because it's all about debugging.